# PHP How to display data from database in specific column

Tags: php, mysql

Once I try to query data on the database so that it can be displayed on a dropdown menu for selection.  Instead, it is displayed other data of the same column. In this example, I want to get the title numbers that are registered with email on the session. I am getting title numbers not registered with the specified email.

In this example, I want to get the title numbers that are registered with email on the session. I am getting title numbers not registered with the specified email.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select name="email" id="email" class="form-control" onChange="getCat(this.value);" required="">
<option value="">Select Title No.</option>
<?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select titleNo  from pic where name='".$_SESSION['email']."' ");
while ($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($rw['titleNo']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($rw['titleNo']);?></option>
<?php
```

I expect to get a display of titles registered with the email on the database.

Comment: make a div and put there the output of your data

Comment: Did you check `$_SESSION['email']` value? If it's returning other rows, then probably you are not selecting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the name instead of the email address.
I would strongly suggest you to start sanitizing your inputs.

Comment: The inputs are correct. The problem is that it is displaying other rows instead of the row I need it displayed.The column that has emails is called: name while the other column is called: titleNo

Comment: If it's displaying another rows (or not the one that you want to display) it's highly probably that you have a data problem.
It will display all rows that has the Session email in name column :S

Comment: How do I solve the data problem, since it is displaying other rows that do not have Session email

Comment: That is happening probably because your $_SESSION['email'] is empty.